# WndProc never receives any WM_COMMAND messages?

Tags: c++, winapi, frameworks

I'm creating a simple framework over Win32, and I can't seem to catch any `WM_COMMAND` messages. I printed all the messages going through my WndProc to the output console, and there are no `WM_COMMAND` messages. My program consists of a window and an editbox (with the "EDIT" class).

Here is my makeshift message loop (it's just for testing):

```
MSG msg;
BOOL ret;
while( ( ret = ::GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) ) > 0 )
{
    if(msg.hwnd == NULL)
        continue;
    else if(ret == -1)
        break;
    else {
        ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
        ::DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
}
```

Here is the WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Win32Base::GlobalWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Win32Base *pWindow;

    pWindow = reinterpret_cast<Win32Base*>( GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_USERDATA ) );
    if( pWindow ) {
        MSG msgdata;
        msgdata.hwnd = hWnd;
        msgdata.message = msg;
        msgdata.wParam = wParam;
        msgdata.lParam = lParam;

        return pWindow->OnMessage( msgdata );
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I am also subclassing the editbox. I can catch it's `WM_CHAR` messages and such, but there are no `WM_COMMAND` messages (however, they shouldn't be there I don't think).

I feel like the problem could be perhaps in the way I am handling parenting. I've added dynamic changing of a windows parent, and when a control is created, there is a chance it won't have a parent yet. So if I create a control with the `WS_CHILD`, it will cause an error because there is no parent. So, when I assign the parent, I also append the `WS_CHILD` style (or remove it, if I am removing the parent). Is this a good practice? Maybe it could be preventing the main window from receiving the editbox's WM_COMMAND messages?

Also, the editbox doesn't repaint itself when I type, I have to force it to repaint, which is very slow...

Comment: If the editbox doesn't repaint itself when you type, then there is something extremely wrong with your code... Are you forwarding messages you don't handle on `OnMessage`?

Comment: Unrelated, but you need to use [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `SetWindowLongPtr` (note the `Ptr` suffix) instead of `Get/SetWindowLong` if you want your code to work on 64-bit Windows.  Otherwise, the pointer to your `Win32Base` object will get truncated.

Comment: Your `else if(ret == -1)` will never be true. You can safely remove it. Apart from that, an EDIT control will never receive `WM_COMMAND` messages. `WM_COMMAND` messages are sent to the **parent** of a BUTTON control when the button is clicked, or to the owner of a MENU when a command is selected.

Comment: All messages that aren't handled are sent to `DefWindowProc`. And thanks for the tip about `SetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLongPtr` I didn't know that. If WM_COMMAND isn't sent by an editbox, what does it send when the text is changed, for example?

Comment: When text in an edit control changes it sends an [`EN_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761676.aspx) notification to its parent. Here is a complete list of [Edit Control Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485924.aspx).

Comment: @Tim Oh? I thought that `EN_CHANGE` would be in the `wParam` high word of the `WM_COMMAND` message.

Comment: That is correct, most of the edit control notification messages are sent in the form of `WM_COMMAND` messages. These messages are sent to the **parent** of the edit control; an edit control will never receive a `WM_COMMAND` message.

Comment: One more thing, unrelated to your question: Using `GWLP_USERDATA` is fairly unreliable, since everyone can read and write to it. A more robust solution is to allocate additional space through `cbWndExtra` in the [`WNDCLASS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx) and store the pointer there.

Comment: @Tim: because this is a subclassed EDIT, you can't even use the cbWndExtra bits, since those belong fully to the EDIT - as does the _USERDATA. Good suggestion if he fully owned the HWND and its class outright, though. Using GetProp() is an alternative when subclassing.

Answer (score 3):

The edit control caches its parent window when it is created and never updates this, so even when you re-parent an edit control it will still send notification messages to the original parent.

One solution would be to create a dummy "wrapper" window class which hosts the edit control, and forwards notification messages sent from the edit control to its parent.

Comment: Darn, I thought about doing this, but then I found the method I was using now and thought I could work around it. I'll try this out.